# Overloaded Generics in Java

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to do this in Java, like C#?

```
public interface BaseFragmentPresenter<T>
{
    void init(T view);
}

public interface BaseFragmentPresenter<T,V>
{
    void init(T view, V relativeView);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: No, you can't have two different interfaces with the same name.

Comment: No, because of type erasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like you want to call two different interface methods, each named `init`, and each passed view(s) of any sub-type. Would this suit your needs?

```
public interface BaseFragmentPresenter
{
    void init(View view);
    void init(View view, View relativeView);
}
```

Using `View` will allow you to pass in a view of any type.